# Communicating between Android and NativeActivity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-ndk, ogre

I am working on an android app where I have a 3D part with most of the app's functionallity written in C++ using ogre. Some features (like the UI for search etc) are implemented using normal android UI. Up until now I used JNI for communicating between those two and directly started the rendering thread from java and managed it from there. However this leeds to some very messy code.

Now Ive stumbled across NativeActivity with its own thread and really like it. However - I still need to initiate some procedures in the rendering engine from java and the other way around. For this I would like to be able to send events to the native code that are handled like sensor event in the NativeActivity's thread. To initiate Java procedures from C++ I could simply perform JNI calls and post them on the UI thread (im open for sugestions if anyone has a better idea).

So the main question is: Is there a way I can (in Java) pass the NativeActivity some event-like objects that are then handled in my main native loop inside the NativeActivity using C code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can pass jObject in jni method and handle it into the c/c++ code.

Comment: I am aware of that. I was wondering if there was a mecahnism provided by android where I wouldnt have to do much manually and didnt have to differentiate much (codewise) between sensor event and custom events form my android ui.

Comment: if java api available than you can use directly other wise you have to use  jni for custom events

Comment: Well that is my question - is there some api or third party library available for thsi task.

Comment: OpenGL you can use directly for rendering & 3D graphics it available in android framework.